# Do i need to create automapper createmap both ways?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, viewmodel, automapper

This might be a stupid question! (n00b to AutoMapper and time-short!)

I want to use AutoMapper to map from EF4 entities to ViewModel classes.

1) If I call

```
CreateMap<ModelClass, ViewModelClass>()
```

then do I also need to call

```
CreateMap<ViewModelClass, ModelClass>()
```

to perform the reverse?

2) If two classes have the same property names, then do I need a CreateMap statement at all, or is this just for "specific/custom" mappings?

Comment: Use `CreateMap<in,out>().ReverseMap()` with all the chained trimmings will save you some keystrokes -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490456/automapper-bidirectional-mapping-with-reversemap-and-formember

Comment: One thing to note is that using ReverseMap with AssertConfigurationIsValid, is that the reverse side will not be validated. I have begun to prefer explicit maps for both sides to ensure that properties added to one side or the other don't get missed in validation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In AutoMapper you have a Source type and a Destination type. So you will be able to map between this Source type and Destination type only if you have a corresponding CreateMap. So to answer your questions:

1. You don't *need to* define the reverse mapping. You have to do it only if you intend to map back.
2. Yes, you need to call CreateMap to indicate that those types are mappable otherwise an exception will be thrown when you call `Map<TSource, TDest>` telling you that a mapping doesn't exist between the source and destination type.

Comment: I know this is not the place to ask questions. Usually I'm using AutoMapper to initiate an Entity object with DTO and DTO is the only model I use in client application. My question is about reading from Database, In that time I've a collection of Entity model which should initiate DTO model. Do I need to create another reverse mapping ?

Comment: @saber yes. I mean that's what I am doing unless someone else proofs the reverse.

Comment: The question still remains, WHY do we have to call `CreateMap`? Forcing me to manually designate mapping isn't being true to the whole "auto" part of things...

Answer (score 139):

For the info of the people who stumble upon this question. There appears to be now a built-in way to achieve a reverse mapping by adding a `.ReverseMap()` call at the end of your `CreateMap()` configuration chain.

Comment: Apparently it was included [a couple months after the first answer](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/commit/bff6e2aa49af3e7b50f527376da48924efa7d81e)

Comment: `.ReverseMap()` doesn't work for `.ForMember(dest => dest.prop, opt => optMapFrom(src => src.prop))`

Answer (score 11):

I've used an extension method do mapping both ways

```
    public static IMappingExpression<TDestination, TSource> BothWays<TSource, TDestination>
        (this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> mappingExpression)
    {
        return Mapper.CreateMap<TDestination, TSource>();
    }
```

usage:

```
 CreateMap<Source, Dest>().BothWays();
```

Comment: I think this extension already exists as `.ReverseMap()` i.e. `CreateMap<In,Out>().ReverseMap()` as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18490071/1037948)...and as I just noticed on [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11673804/1037948)

Comment: I think ReverseMap was added after Feb 2012.

Comment: maybe, I'm just going by [the commit timestamp](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/commit/bff6e2aa49af3e7b50f527376da48924efa7d81e) of Nov 2011

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, or you can call `CreateMap<ModelClass, ViewModelClass>().ReverseMap()`.
2. If two classes have same `Member`(Property,Field,GetMethod()), you needn't call `CreateMap<TSrc,TDest>`. Actually, if every `member` in `TDest` are all exist in `TSrc`, you needn't call `CreateMap<TSrc,TDest>`. The following code works.

```cs
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }  
}
class Person2
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int? Age { get; set; }
   public DateTime BirthTime { get; set; }
}
public class NormalProfile : Profile
{
    public NormalProfile()
    {
       //CreateMap<Person2, Person>();//
    }
}
   
var cfg = new MapperConfiguration(c => 
{ 
    c.AddProfile<NormalProfile>();
});
//cfg.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
var mapper = cfg.CreateMapper();
var s3 = mapper.Map<Person>(new Person2 { Name = "Person2" });
```