# Automapper: bidirectional mapping with ReverseMap() and ForMember()

Tags: .net, automapper, bidirectional

I have the case where I want to map an entity to a viewmodel and back. I have to specify the mapping explicitly with `ForMember()` because their properties do not share the exact same names. Here is a short example of how my classes look like:

```
public class PartTwo {
    public int Integer { get; set; }
}

public class PartTwoViewModel {
    public int PartInteger { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to use them this way:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PartTwo, PartTwoViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.PartInteger, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Integer))
    .ReverseMap();

var partTwoViewModel = new PartTwoViewModel() { PartInteger = 42 };
var partTwo = Mapper.Map<PartTwoViewModel, PartTwo>(partTwoViewModel);
Assert.AreEqual(partTwoViewModel.PartInteger, partTwo.Integer);
```

But it does not match the property `PartInteger` to `Integer`. (`Integer` is `0`.)

Is there a way to make this work? (When the properties of both classes have the same names it works.) Do I have to set some kind of option in the method `ForMember()`?

Comment: I just tried to use `ReverseMap` the way you did, and it works well. This question is outdated.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You could define your configuration like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PartTwo, PartTwoViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.PartInteger, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Integer));

Mapper.CreateMap<PartTwoViewModel, PartTwo>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Integer, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PartInteger));
```

**UPDATE**

Here is [the commit](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/commit/bff6e2aa49af3e7b50f527376da48924efa7d81e) where `ReverseMap` was initially implemented. From what I can see in the code, it only creates a simple reverse mapping. For example, in this case it would automatically configure the equivalent of:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PartTwoViewModel, PartTwo>();
```

To get anything more complex, I'm afraid that you're going to have to configure it manually.

Comment: Yes this works. I hoped that I would not have to define the reverse mapping, because I have many properties which I map via ForMember().

Comment: One thing to note is that using ReverseMap with AssertConfigurationIsValid, is that the reverse side will not be validated. I have begun to prefer explicit maps for both sides to ensure that properties added to one side or the other don't get missed in validation.

Answer (score 169):

`ReverseMap` returns an `IMappingExpression` that represents the reversal of the mapping. Once you call, it subsequent calls will be for configuring the reversal of the map.

Here's an example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CartItemDto, CartItemModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.ExtendedCost, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .ReverseMap()
          .ForMember(dest => dest.Pricing, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

This will ignore the `Pricing` field in the reverse direction.

Comment: Excellent. While it's still inconvenient to have to create the member mappings again, this is better than having to create an entirely new map.

Comment: @jon Wingfield  I appreciate your answer, but I am also a little confused.  If I still have to re-do all of may .ForMember calls after I call ReverseMap, is it gaining me anything?  Is it just a that .ignore is broken?

Comment: @JMarsch It's been a while, but I don't think you need to redo _all_ the `ForMember` calls, just anything that isn't already mapped.