# Automapper not mapping different property names

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a DTO class called `CarDataDTO` with two properties named as below:

```
 public decimal FuelTankSize { get; set; }
 public decimal CarEngineOutput { get; set; }
```

I am using `Dapper` and I can see the Data getting returned and mapped to the properties in the DTO as expected.

I am using WebAPI to return Data to UI - the properties on the UI are named differently as below in a class called `CarData`

```
 public decimal Size { get; set; }
 public decimal EngineOutput { get; set; }
```

So I am attempting to use Automapper to map these properties as below - I have an Automapper config class with an Initialize method which is called in `Application_Start` in the `Global.asax.cs`

```
config.CreateMap<CarData, CarDataDTO>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.FuelTankSize, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Size))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.CarEngineOutput, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EngineOutput))
      .ReverseMap();
```

I am then getting then Data in the WebAPI method from the DB where it is a list of data and returning it as below:

```
var carData = _myService.GetAllCarData().ToList();
//error checking etc removed for brevity
return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CarDataDTO>, IEnumerable<CarData>>(carData);
```

With a breakpoint set on the carData line I can see that FuelTankSize and CarEngineOutput have values from the DB as expected - but when I run in PostMan the values for Size and EngineOutput are `0`

Comment: You need to specify the mapping in the `Initialize` method the other way round when you want to map it this way.

Comment: does using ReverseMap not do that?

Comment: Similar question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490456/automapper-bidirectional-mapping-with-reversemap-and-formember)

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders - cheers - never found that doing a search - I'll give the answer in that a go - looks like ReverseMap is only for straightforward cases