# Customize mapping a property from destination to source and reverse map

Tags: c#, automapper

In order to save changes to my db, I am using Automapper to map a property of type string from `destination` to a property of type int in `source`.

I have tried `ForMember` but it works for source to destination only.

So how can I map a property named `IpPort` of type string in class `B` to a property named `IpPort` of type int in class `A`.

Class A and B are mapped like this:

```
cf.CreateMap<classA, classB>().ReverseMap();
```

Comment: something like `ForMember(dest => dest.IpPort , 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => int.Parse(src.IpPort )));`

Comment: @Aria that works for source to destination,  I want the oposite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper: bidirectional mapping with ReverseMap() and ForMember()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490456/automapper-bidirectional-mapping-with-reversemap-and-formember)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening) main site said you can use `ForPath` for customizing reverse map .

So you can use `ForPath` liek below:

```
 CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>()
    .ForMember(d => dest.IpPort , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => int.Parse(src.IpPort )));
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForPath(s => s.IntPort, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IntPort.ToString()));
```

or you can use `AferMap` and check the type of source and destination type like

```
AutoMapper.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>().ReverseMap().AfterMap((source, destination) =>
        {
            object ob = (object)source;
           string type= ob.GetType().ToString();
            if(type == "ClassA")
                //Do something
             else
                //Do something
        })
```