# AutoMapper .ReverseMap() .Ignore() not working

Tags: automapper, automapper-6

Having an issue with version 6.1.1. In the below, the result of the reverse map still has the Company object populated. Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490456/automapper-bidirectional-mapping-with-reversemap-and-formember), which shows what I am doing below, except they are ignoring a property, and I'm ignoring a complex object.

What am I missing?

```
CreateMap<Item, ItemViewModel>(MemberList.Destination)
.ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(x => x.Company, x => x.Ignore())
    ;
```

Comment: Try the latest.

Answer (score 1):

With AutoMapper 6.1 you could use `ForPath` instead `ForMember` to ignore complex objects.
See [How to ignore property with ReverseMap](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2195) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

I see not what is wrong, but here is a running sample:

```
namespace AutomapperTest2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        #region Methods

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Configure the mappings
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<ApplicantEducation, ApplicantEducationVM>();
                cfg.CreateMap<Applicant, ApplicantVM>().ReverseMap()
                    .ForMember(x => x.Education, x => x.Ignore());
            });


            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            Applicant ap = new Applicant
            {
                Name = "its me",
                Education =
                    new ApplicantEducation
                    {
                        SomeInt = 10,
                        SomeString = "sampleString"
                    }
            };
            // Map
            ApplicantVM apVm = Mapper.Map<Applicant, ApplicantVM>(ap);
            Applicant apBack = Mapper.Map<ApplicantVM, Applicant>(apVm);
        }

        #endregion
    }


    /// Your source classes
    public class Applicant
    {   
        public ApplicantEducation Education { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }   
    }

    public class ApplicantEducation
    {
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }    
    }

    // Your VM classes
    public class ApplicantVM
    { 
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ApplicantEducationVM Education { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }            
    }


    public class ApplicantEducationVM
    {    
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

}