# AutoMapper: Does Map <A,B> give <B,A>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

Using **Automapper** I create a simple map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyCustomerDTO, YourCustomerDTO>()
```

I often need to **go the other way too**. Do I need to also create the mapping the other way, or will Automapper infer it based on the above mapping?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<YourCustomerDTO, MyCustomerDTO>()   //Needed?
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. you must create two way mapping. A good helper method for two way mapping could be :

```
 protected virtual void ViceVersa<T1, T2>()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<T1, T2>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<T2, T1>();
        }
```

then use it like this :

```
ViceVersa<T1, T2>();
```

Comment: Note that this can now be done "out of the box" with the `ReverseMap` option.

Answer (score 23):

This is a duplicate to [Do i need to create automapper createmap both ways?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185026/do-i-need-to-create-automapper-createmap-both-ways)

Note the answer regarding `.ReverseMap()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11673804/1505426).

Note that `.ReverseMap()` is for basic mapping. If you need to use options (such as specific  `ForMember` mappings), you will need to create a custom reverse map.

Answer (score 2):

you need to create second mapping as well. A simple test trying to run your app without second mapping will give you a runtime error

Comment: I don't think it gives a compilation error if I remember correctly... it gives a runtime error? No mapping for B,A found or something along those lines?

Comment: that's right... I remembered that it gives some kind of an error.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same issue when working with AutoMapper, and @Behnam-Esmaili is a good answer but it could be improved.

You could implement a extension method for `IMapperConfigurationExpression` which would do this two way mapping and also expecting two optional parameter (`Action<IMappingExpression<T, Y>>`) which would be used when trying to configure the Mappings for both types.

```
public static class ModelMapper
{
    private static readonly IMapper _mapper;

    static ModelMapper()
    {
        var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.CreateTwoWayMap<CustomerViewModel, Customer>(
                secondExpression: (exp) => exp.ForMember((source) => source.CustomerEmail, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Email)));
        });

        _mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
    }

    public static void CreateTwoWayMap<T, Y>(this IMapperConfigurationExpression config, 
        Action<IMappingExpression<T, Y>> firstExpression = null,
        Action<IMappingExpression<Y, T>> secondExpression = null)
    {
        var mapT = config.CreateMap<T, Y>();
        var mapY = config.CreateMap<Y, T>();

        firstExpression?.Invoke(mapT);
        secondExpression?.Invoke(mapY);
    }

    public static T Map<T>(object model)
    {
        return _mapper.Map<T>(model);
    }
}
```

The implementation above is a one way of achieving it, however it can be design differently.